# Install package from lerna-managed monorepo via git URL

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

I am using yarn for my project. My project has a dependency which happened to be a subpackage of larger monorepo maintained by lerna.
The subpackage was updated but not published yet and I need that unpublished code. Is there any way to install lerna's subpackage via git url?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same issue except in my case the subpackage hasn't been updated - I cloned it and updated myself, but can't figure out how to install my version (`yarn add git://github.com/MY-USERNAME/REPONAME` doesn't work, neither does `yarn add git://github.com/MY-USERNAME/REPONAME/packages/PACKAGE-NAME`).

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn’t find solution of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install package from github repo subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194648/npm-install-package-from-github-repo-subfolder)

Answer (score 2):

If your questions is "How do I install a sub-package via git?" then that would be a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194648/npm-install-package-from-github-repo-subfolder), which it sounds like you kind of can do, but it does not look fun. But npm on its own does not support installs of git subdirectories.

A better solution would be either to do a release of the package with a npm `beta` tag and target it directly in your package.json. Or to set up the lerna project locally and run `npm link` to use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try GitPkg: https://gitpkg.vercel.app/.

> Using sub folders of a repo as yarn/npm dependencies made easy