# NPM install part from github monorepo

Tags: npm

I'm trying to install **typescript** plugin from [rollup plugins monorepo](https://github.com/rollup/plugins) (actually a branch with a PR from this repo).

I guess the following command tries to install the whole repo:

`npm install git+https://github.com/rollup/plugins.git`.

It also fails at their `disallow-npm.js`, I guess a guard for this kind of thing.

How can I pull and install only one plugin from this monorepo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install package from lerna-managed monorepo via git URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064570/install-package-from-lerna-managed-monorepo-via-git-url)

Answer (score -1):

relating to your problem I found an article that talks about installation of NPM modules from Github repos:

[How to install NPM modules from Github Repos](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a)

Being more accurate to your question, that repo has a Readme on each package that you can use to install the modules from that Github repo.

```
npm install @rollup/plugin-alias
```

The code about should be valid to install the module "plugin-alias" from that "rollup" repo.

I hope this helps to solve your problem, regards.

Comment: But how to install directly from github? I want to install a branch with a fix that hasn't been released yet. Note that this is a `monorepo` containing multiple plugins, not a simple repo.

Comment: As the port says, you can use that command to install a whole repo:

`npm install --save username/repo#branch-name-or-commit-or-tag`

This way you will install all the modules from that repo. 

I hope that is what you are looking for and helps to clarify your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me. This command pulls all `monorepo` containing all plugins and fails to install. I want a single plugin.

Comment: @LorenzoGómez you said "repo has a Readme on each package that you can use to install the modules from that Github repo", is that true? I browse to rollup legacy version at the date around your post, and didn't see such thing. it only had npm install from npm repo. https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/1cd7721ff12b03c951a4ca0516e868b80a52f302/packages/alias
I m looking for a way to install packages of mono repo from GitHub Url, but so far I didn't find a possible way...

Comment: this command is not helpful when the repo is a monorepo.
the point of the question is to pull one package from that monorepo, using the git[hub] URL.Because we may want the package from a branch or fork that is not published, for example.