# Is it possible to install a npm module from gitlab private repository sub-folder?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab

For starters, my question is not same as [Install npm module from gitlab private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988876/install-npm-module-from-gitlab-private-repository)

We maintain our own npm modules, each in its own sub-folder and together compose a repo, say my_node_modules.git, so is it possible to install a single npm module from it, i.e. is there a command/tool I can use to

npm i -S git+ssh://git@mydomain/path/my_node_modules.git/**A_module**/
npm i -S git+ssh://git@mydomain/path/my_node_modules.git/**B_module**/

If not what other solution I have to install that individual private module ?

---- update ----

After doing some research I found I am not alone here.
So npm is against it, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974
yarn is considering it, https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725

I really don't like the idea here [npm install package from github repo subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194648/npm-install-package-from-github-repo-subfolder), the `postinstall sript`

I am thinking about using git subtree. I leave my question here to see if someone can come up some ideas.

Comment: I also need this approach. Have you found the solution?

Comment: I did find a solution for that. https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-directory-deploy

Comment: @Qiulang can you provide some guide on how `git-directory-deploy` works to you? I also need to install a package which belongs to a private mono-repo on GitHub. `GitPkg` works for sub-folder packages but it doesn't support private repo. Thanks.

Comment: This is a rather old question I need to take some time to think about my then solution again.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not that hard to just publish your package into gitlab registry. It can obviously be done from `.gitlab-ci.yml` no matter how nested your module is. See [gitlab guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/) for more details.

`git-directory-deploy` is not the right tool for this job and any other approach(like https://gitpkg.now.sh/) will add a level of indirection anyway.